# Creating a continuous animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

I want to create an animation that moves up or down the screen according to how fast the user taps the screen. The problem I am having is that I don't know how to create an infinite loop so I am firing a timer which presents issues. Here is my current code.

```
-(void)setPosOfCider {
    CGFloat originalY = CGRectGetMinY(cider.frame);
    float oY = originalY;
    float posY = averageTapsPerSecond * 100;
    float dur = 0;
    dur = (oY - posY) / 100;
    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:dur animations:^(void) {
        cider.frame = CGRectMake(768, 1024 - posY, 768, 1024);
    }];
}
```

Suggested fix(Doesn't work):

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 3, 1024); // 3 pages wide.
    scroll.delegate = self;

    self.speedInPointsPerSecond = 200000;
    self.tapEvents = [NSMutableArray array];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self startDisplayLink];
}

-(IBAction)tapped {
    [self.tapEvents addObject:[NSDate date]];

    // if less than two taps, no average speed

    if ([self.tapEvents count] < 1)
        return;

    // only average the last three taps

    if ([self.tapEvents count] > 2)
        [self.tapEvents removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    // now calculate the average taps per second of the last three taps

    NSDate *start = self.tapEvents[0];
    NSDate *end   = [self.tapEvents lastObject];

    self.averageTapsPerSecond = [self.tapEvents count] / [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
}

- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    self.lastTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (CGFloat)yAxisValueBasedUponTapsPerSecond
{
    CGFloat y = 1024 - (self.averageTapsPerSecond * 100.0);

    return y;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    CFTimeInterval now = CACurrentMediaTime();
    CGFloat elapsed = now - self.lastTime;
    self.lastTime = now;
    if (elapsed <= 0) return;

    CGPoint center = self.cider.center;
    CGFloat destinationY = [self yAxisValueBasedUponTapsPerSecond];

    if (center.y == destinationY)
    {
        // we don't need to move it at all

        return;
    }
    else if (center.y > destinationY)
    {
        // we need to move it up

        center.y -= self.speedInPointsPerSecond * elapsed;
        if (center.y < destinationY)
            center.y = destinationY;
    }
    else
    {
        // we need to move it down

        center.y += self.speedInPointsPerSecond * elapsed;
        if (center.y > destinationY)
            center.y = destinationY;
    }

    self.cider.center = center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An even simpler approach is to employ the [`UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions) option when using block-based animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     // set the new frame
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

That stops the current block-based animation and starts the new one from the current location. Note, effective iOS 8 and later, this is now the default behavior, generally obviating the need for the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` altogether. In fact, the default behavior considers not only the position of the view in question, but also the current velocity, ensuring a smooth transition. See WWDC 2014 video [Building Interruptible and Responsive Interactions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=236) for more information.)

---

Another approach would be to have your taps (which adjust the `averageTapsPerSecond`) to stop any existing animation, grab the view's current `frame` from the presentation layer (which reflects the state of the view mid-animation), and then just start a new animation:

```
// grab the frame from the presentation layer (which is the frame mid-animation)

CALayer *presentationLayer = self.viewToAnimate.layer.presentationLayer;
CGRect frame = presentationLayer.frame;

// stop the animation

[self.viewToAnimate.layer removeAllAnimations];

// set the frame to be location we got from the presentation layer

self.viewToAnimate.frame = frame;

// now, starting from that location, animate to the new frame

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    self.viewToAnimate.frame = ...; // set the frame according to the averageTapsPerSecond
} completion:nil];
```

In iOS 7, you would use the rendition of `animateWithDuration` with the `initialSpringVelocity:` parameter, to ensure a smooth transition from the object's current movement to the new animation. See the aforementioned [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions) for examples.

---

Original answer:

To adjust a view on the basis of the number of taps per second, you could use a `CADisplayLink`, which is like a `NSTimer`, but ideally suited for animation efforts like this. Bottom line, translate your `averageTapsPerSecond` into a `y` coordinate, and then use the `CADisplayLink` to animate the moving of some view to that `y` coordinate:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (nonatomic) CFTimeInterval lastTime;

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat speedInPointsPerSecond;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tapEvents;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat averageTapsPerSecond;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.speedInPointsPerSecond = 200.0;
    self.tapEvents = [NSMutableArray array];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    [self.tapEvents addObject:[NSDate date]];

    // if less than two taps, no average speed

    if ([self.tapEvents count] < 2)
        return;

    // only average the last three taps

    if ([self.tapEvents count] > 3)
        [self.tapEvents removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    // now calculate the average taps per second of the last three taps

    NSDate *start = self.tapEvents[0];
    NSDate *end   = [self.tapEvents lastObject];

    self.averageTapsPerSecond = [self.tapEvents count] / [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
}

- (CGFloat)yAxisValueBasedUponTapsPerSecond
{
    CGFloat y = 480 - self.averageTapsPerSecond * 100.0;

    return y;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self startDisplayLink];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self stopDisplayLink];
}

- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    self.lastTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    CFTimeInterval now = CACurrentMediaTime();
    CGFloat elapsed = now - self.lastTime;
    self.lastTime = now;
    if (elapsed <= 0) return;

    CGPoint center = self.viewToAnimate.center;
    CGFloat destinationY = [self yAxisValueBasedUponTapsPerSecond];

    if (center.y == destinationY)
    {
        // we don't need to move it at all

        return;
    }
    else if (center.y > destinationY)
    {
        // we need to move it up

        center.y -= self.speedInPointsPerSecond * elapsed;
        if (center.y < destinationY)
            center.y = destinationY;
    }
    else
    {
        // we need to move it down

        center.y += self.speedInPointsPerSecond * elapsed;
        if (center.y > destinationY)
            center.y = destinationY;
    }

    self.viewToAnimate.center = center;
}

@end
```

Hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Also, to use the above, make sure you've added the QuartzCore framework to your project (though in Xcode 5, it seems to do that for you).

---

For standard, constant speed animation, you can use the following:

You would generally do this with an animation that repeats (i.e. `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`) and that autoreverses (i.e. `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     cider.frame = ... // specify the end destination here
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

For a simple up-down-up animation, that's all you need. No timers needed.

Comment: The end destination is variable and so is the duration. I use this and it doesn't work at all. I'll update my current post

Comment: @SHERRIECRANE My original answer shows you how to do a simple repeating animation. Start at one position, do a `animateWithDuration` specifying the final position, and repeat and autoreverse. If you want to change either the speed or the end location (I wasn't sure which you were trying to do), you would abandon standard animations and animate yourself using `CADisplayLink`. See my revised answer.

Comment: I am trying to understand the CADisplayLink but it just moves upwards constantly, then resets.

Comment: @SHERRIECRANE The concept is that a `CADisplayLink` is just like a timer, except it's optimized to fire whenever it can update the screen (and it replaces any existing animation blocks or timers). You're manually controlling the calculation of where it should be at any moment of time. My code sample stops going up when `y` hits 50 and it turns around and goes down. I'm not sure why yours moves "upwards constantly and resets" as there's really not much to this. You should log your `y` variable, see when it's getting "reset", why it's not turning around, etc.

Comment: So if I want it to move to a position based on a variable, I can do this how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37905/discussion-between-rob-and-sherrie-crane)

Comment: Following on from out conversation earlier I have tried to implement your suggestions but it does not work. I will update my original post.

Comment: I have tried to use this but with a button instead and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @SHERRIECRANE Your `handleDisplayLink` differs quite significantly from the one in my answer above. You appear to be trying to set the `center` to be the final destination, but you don't want to do that. You only want to nudge the `center` towards the final destination at some predetermined rate.

Comment: @SHERRIECRANE I've added an even simpler solution in my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is one line you need to add to Rob's answer.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:dur delay:del options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VAL];

    //Your code here

} completion:nil];
```

If you need to stop that animation, use this line (remember to add QuartzCore framework):

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: No, if you use `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`, there's no need to set the number of iterations. That's only needed if you're doing the non-block-based animation. I think the issue is that the OP wants to change the speed of the animation, which I think pushes her into the world of `CADisplayLink` (or timers).

Comment: You're right. For that additional feature, timer could be the most flexible way to go.

Comment: Agreed. Frankly, `CADisplayLink` is often recommended in favor of timers for animations, but I think you're right.